# How do I check if a dictionary has a key in it in Julia?

Tags: data-structures, julia

Suppose I have a `Dict` object and a key value and I want to see if there's already an entry in the dictionary for that key? How do I do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Suppose this is your dictionary:

```
d = Dict(
    "aardvark" => 1,
    "bear"     => 2,
    "cat"      => 3,
    "dog"      => 4,
)
```

If you have a key you can check for its presence using the `haskey` function:

```
julia> haskey(d, "cat")
true

julia> haskey(d, "zebra")
false
```

A slightly fancier way to check this is to check if the key is in the set of keys returned by calling `keys(d)`:

```
julia> ks = keys(d)
Base.KeySet for a Dict{String,Int64} with 4 entries. Keys:
  "aardvark"
  "bear"
  "cat"
  "dog"

julia> "cat" in ks
true

julia> "zebra" in ks
false
```

Finally, it's fairly common that you want to get the value associated with a key if it is present in the dictionary. You can do that as a separate step by doing `d[k]` after checking that `k` is present in `keys(d)` but that involves an additional dictionary lookup. Instead, if there is some sentinel value that you know cannot be a value in your dictionary, such as `nothing`, then you can use the `get` function to look up the key with a default:

```
v = get(d, k, nothing)
if v !== nothing
    # keys(d) contains k
end
```

If you know nothing about the kinds of values that `d` can map keys to, this is not a safe option since it could be the case that the pair `k => nothing` is present in `d`.

Comment: Is one of them faster or all have the same complexity? I assume the last one is slower, since it has an extra step, but I wouldn't bet on that...

Comment: Should all be the same. But checking for a key and then getting it separately is slower than doing `get(d, k, nothing)` and comparing with `nothing`.

Answer (score 4):

Ok not exactly an answer but still relevant to the discussion, something I learnt recently about julia dictionary accessor method that has made my life a lot easier.

```
val = get(dict, "key", nothing)
```

also has a version that creates the dictionary entry and sets it to the default value if it does not already exist

```
val = get!(dict, "key", nothing)
```

which does away with writing a lot of blocks like this

```
if !haskey(dict, "key") 
    dict["key"] = nothing 
end
val = dict["key"]
```

so now instead of littering your code with key checks and dictionary value initialization blocks you can use get! instead.